# Change byte in int - casting byte to an integer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, int

I'm streaming data from the server. Server sends various BigEndian variables, but also sends bytes (representing number). One of my `SocketClient.read` overloads accepts `(int length, char* array)`. I want to **pass an integer variable pointer** to this function to **get 0-255 value** in it (unsigned byte).

#### What have I tried:

```
unsigned int UNSIGNED_BYTE;
socket.read(1, &((char*)&UNSIGNED_BYTE)[0]);  //I am changing 1st byte of a variable - C++ uses little endian
//I know that function reads 6, and that is what I find in 1st byte
std::cout<<(int)((char*)&UNSIGNED_BYTE)[0]<<")\n";  //6   - correct
std::cout<<UNSIGNED_BYTE<<")\n";  //3435973638   -What the hell?
```

According to the above, I am changing the **wrong part of the `int`**. But **what else should I change**?

#### My class declaration and implementation:

```
/*Declares:*/
bool read(int bytes, char *text);
/*Implements:*/
bool SocketClient::read(int bytes, char *text) {
      //boost::system::error_code error;
      char buffer = 0;
      int length = 0;
      while(bytes>0) {
        try
        {
          size_t len = sock.receive(boost::asio::buffer(&buffer, 1));  //Read a byte to a buffer
        }
        catch(const boost::system::system_error& ex) {
            std::cout<<"Socket exception: "<<ex.code()<<'\n';
            return false;   //Happens when peer disconnects for example
        }
        if(byteEcho)
            std::cout<<(int)(unsigned char)buffer<<' ';
        bytes--;      //Decrease ammount to read
        text[length] = buffer;
        length++;
        
      }
      return true;
}
```

Comment: `//... C++ uses little endian`, When did this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So firstly:

```
unsigned int UNSIGNED_BYTE;
```

Probably isn't very helpfully named since I very much doubt the architecture you're using defines an `int` as an 8 bit unsigned integer additionally **you're not initializing this to zero** and then later **you're writing to only part of it** leaving the rest as garbage.  It's likely to be 32/64 bits in size on most modern compilers/architectures.

Secondly:

```
socket.read(1, &((char*)&UNSIGNED_BYTE)[0])
```

Is reading 8 bits into a (probably) 32 bit memory location and the correct end to put the 8 bits is not down to C++ (as you say in your comments).  It's actually down to your CPU since endianness is a property of the CPU not the language.  Why don't you read the value into an actual `char` and then simply assign that to an `int` since this will deal with the conversion for you **and will make your code portable**.

Comment: Just wanted to be cool and avoid initialising useless variables :D Under such circumstances, I will cast `char` to `int`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was, that I did not **initialise the int**. Though the 1st byte was changed, other 3 bytes had random values.
This makes the solution very simple (and also makes my question be likely to be closed as *Too localised*):

unsigned int UNSIGNED_BYTE = 0;

Comment: Careful though, this code won't currently be portable, see my answer.